# Android - layout_weight makes image clickable on the sides

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout of 3 images. I assigned weights to each of them to control 
the width they allocate.

The problem is that the weight makes all the width of the image
clickable, when I want the clickable area to be the image only, how can i achieve that?

This is the relevant part of the layout:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/2" 
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/2"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/3"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to wrap each `ImageView` into a container, e.g. a simple `FrameLayout`. You then set the weights on the container rather than the `ImageView` itself. That way the container will scale, but the images (and hence the clickable area) won't. The downside is that this introduces an extra layer in your view hierarchy.

An alternative could be to check at runtime whether the selection was on the 'visible' area of the image. It will mean more work for you, but potentially less for the system, although the difference is probably marginal at best.

Comment: Ran into same issue and used framelayout to resolve it, thanks!